# Google Cloud SQL - Need Super User Privileges

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We are using Google Cloud SQL for our project but facing some administrative issues around it .

In our cloud DB We have two users like :

root% (any host)
root182.68.122.202

Now we need "SUPER" user access on these two users to perform some admin tasks like modifying the variable 'max_allowed_packet' to higher limit and other related stuff to optimize our functioning .

Like I want to execute one of the command :

SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=32*1024*1024;

But I couldn't find a way from the Google Cloud Console or from the MYSQL itself to get it done as I am getting an error prompting:

"SQL Error (1227) : Access denied ; you need (atleast one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation."

I have even tried a hack to do the direct changes in the "mysql.user" table (making YES to the SUPER privilege) but all futile .

Can you please let me know how can I perform this tasks on my DB ? What is the way to grant these Super Access to the desired users .

Comment: You can change global flags via the console: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags

Answer (score -1):

According to Google’s [Cloud SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users#root-user), the root user has all privileges but SUPER and FILE. It’s a characteristic of the Google Cloud SQL.

But rest assured! You have three other ways of easily changing that global "group by" variable that has been slowing your progress. There’s a neat explanation on this [Configuring database flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#determining_what_database_flags_have_been_set_for_an_instance) this will guide.

I hope this helps others!!!

Answer (score -1):

Google Cloud SQL does not support SUPER privileges, which means that GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES statements will not work. As an alternative, you can use GRANT ALL ON `%`.*.

Comment: this does not work on google cloud SQL

Answer (score -3):

You can edit your running instance.

From the left menu in the SQL section :

1. view your instance detail by clicking on the concerned line
2. click on the "Edit button", in the configuration block, edit the "add database flags" add a new item by choosing in the defined list
3. Don't forget to save your new flag by hitting the "save" button